# DNS challenge from traefik to Vultr

Tags: docker, lets-encrypt, traefik

Is there anybody here who has managed to obtain a SSL certificate from Vultr from within a docker/traefik container.

I have set up my Vultr api key and provided this to my compose file but the DNS challenge simply fails with an “error presenting token” error.

Interested to hear if anyone has successfully done this.

Comment: More details like traefik configuration used, would help others to understand a possible issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See this link
https://github.com/go-acme/lego/pull/1302

The below changes worked for me.

```
    environment:
      - "VULTR_API_KEY=xxxxx"
      - "VULTR_HTTP_TIMEOUT=3600"
```

Comment: Thank you so much - I spent all afternoon yesterday trying to get this to work. Is there a way to force the use of Vultr v2 api from the traefik request?

Comment: Traefik uses [go-acme](https://github.com/go-acme/lego) for the DNS challange which as of version 4.1.3 is still using Vultr v1 API. However, the PR to bump this to Vultr API v2 has been merged and is slated for the 4.2 release [go-acme vultr v2 pr](https://github.com/go-acme/lego/pull/1302). So once this new version is released and updated in traefik it will be running on Vultr API v2.